# Handle Tomcat aborting file upload in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, multipartform-data

Is there a way to handle case when Tomcat aborts file upload due to defined limits, in order to return decent response (for example `413 Payload Too Large`)?

I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.0 with following configuration:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=20MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=21MB
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=21MB
server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size=20MB
```

When trying to upload files larger than 21MB (or 26MB for some reason) using REST API, I receive `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer` because Tomcat aborts the upload (closes the socket), due to defined `maxSwallowSize`. There's no exception in the logs by Spring. When running tests, I can see that `RestTemplate` retries couple of times, but eventually throws exception.

---

You can find [MWE on GitHub](https://github.com/g0loob/large-file-upload-mwe).

Comment: Try `server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=-1` to let Spring completely handle file uploads.

Comment: @Unmitigated Yes, that would yield the expected output, but then someone could upload 10GB file (for example) and eat up the memory (and possibly kill the server). I like that Tomcat is aborting the connection, I just wish I could attach some handler to that action.

Comment: I have the same problem here. Did anyone have a solution for it?