# Spring @ExceptionHandler does not work with IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, exception, illegalargumentexception

I got an API in a Kotlin Spring boot project and I'm customizing my error responses. I have a class for handling the exceptions to show a customized error response. I've added 2 handlers. They work perfectly:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class ControllerExceptionHandlers {

  @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException::class)
  fun constraintViolationException(e: ConstraintViolationException): ResponseEntity<Any> {
    return ResponseEntity
      .status(MyManError.BAD_PARAM_VALIDATION.status)
      .body(
        Error(
          FaultDefinition(
            MyManError.BAD_PARAM_VALIDATION.code,
            MyManError.BAD_PARAM_VALIDATION.name,
            "Parameter type mismatch field: '${e.message}'",
            "Source Name: ${Security.getUserName()}",
            null
          )
        )
      )
  }
  @ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestPartException::class)
  fun missingServletRequestPartException(e: MissingServletRequestPartException): ResponseEntity<Any> {
    return ResponseEntity
      .status(MyManError.BAD_PARAM_VALIDATION.status)
      .body(
        Error(
          FaultDefinition(
            MyManError.BAD_PARAM_VALIDATION.code,
            "BAD_PARAM_${e.requestPartName.toUpperCase()}",
            "Parameter validation failed for field $e.requestPartName",
            "Source Name: ${Security.getUserName()}",
            null
          )
        )
      )
  }
}
```

And I want to add 1 more error handler for `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
  @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException::class)
  fun illegalArgumentException(e: IllegalArgumentException): ResponseEntity<Any> {
    return ResponseEntity
      .status(MyManError.BAD_PARAM_VALIDATION.status)
      .body(
        Error(
          FaultDefinition(
            MyManError.BAD_PARAM_VALIDATION.code,
            MyManError.BAD_PARAM_VALIDATION.name,
            "'${e.message}'",
            "Source Name: ${Security.getUserName()}",
            null
          )
        )
      )
  }
```

I added `server.max-http-header-size` and assigned it to 10KB. So I tried to send 11KB request. But I got the error in log like that:

```
17:09:42.513 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11Processor - Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeaders(Http11InputBuffer.java:603)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:284)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I'm exactly sure I'm importing like `import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` but still it shows the log like that.

Why @ExceptionHandler is not working with `IllegalArgumentException` ? Other handlers are working well but this is not. Can you help me ?

EDIT: One strange thing is; if I add the handler for IllegalArgumentException, but if I do different thing, I can see my customized response like that (and that is as I wanted):

```
{
    "fault": {
        "code": 420018,
        "message": "BAD_PARAM_VALIDATION",
        "description": "'No topic found for name :'my-events.fifo''",
        "source": "Source Name: Wicaledon"
    }
}
```

I'm exactly sure that the new handler handled it because if I remove it, and if I check logs, I see same error as in my customized response:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No topic found for name :'my-events.fifo'
    at io.awspring.cloud.messaging.support.destination.DynamicTopicDestinationResolver.getTopicResourceName(DynamicTopicDestinationResolver.java:94)
    at io.awspring.cloud.messaging.support.destination.DynamicTopicDestinationResolver.resolveDestination(DynamicTopicDestinationResolver.java:72)
    at io.awspring.cloud.messaging.support.destination.DynamicTopicDestinationResolver.resolveDestination(DynamicTopicDestinationResolver.java:36)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.CachingDestinationResolverProxy.resolveDestination(CachingDestinationResolverProxy.java:92)
    at io.awspring.cloud.messaging.core.support.AbstractMessageChannelMessagingSendingTemplate.resolveMessageChannelByLogicalName(AbstractMessageChannelMessagingSendingTemplate.java:94)
    at io.awspring.cloud.messaging.core.support.AbstractMessageChannelMessagingSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageChannelMessagingSendingTemplate.java:75)
```

Comment: That exception is being thrown before the request ever gets to Spring (you can see the lack of any `springframework` in the stack trace).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- is there any solution for that ?

Comment: @Wicaledon 1. examine why do you receive `Request header is too large`. What do you send (or receive) in headers? 2. if there's nothing you can do, adjust limit with `server.max-http-header-size`

Comment: @StefanGolubović ah I forgot to say, yes I added this line to with `10KB`. So I'm just trying to send a 11KB request. I got 400 Bad request as a html

Comment: @StefanGolubović But I want to see a customized response as I added for other errors

Comment: @Wicaledon you'll have to search for a way to customize Tomcat, if it's possible at all. Your request is terminated by Tomcat, and you can't handle those errors within `@ControllerAdvice`. I also [had a problem with Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65873752/handle-tomcat-aborting-file-upload-in-spring-boot), but I still didn't receive any response.

Comment: @StefanGolubović the strange thing is, same exception is working but the reason is `No topic found for name`

Comment: @Wicaledon I did not understand your last comment. If it's relevant, you should edit your question.

Comment: @StefanGolubović I did now, can you check please

Comment: @Wicaledon well, the question is how much different is it. Is it still over the limit? Because you're now receiving an error for not having `my-events.fifo` topic.

Comment: @StefanGolubović no, lower than the limit. error is coming from different reason but same exception name

Comment: @Wicaledon yeah, but now the exception is handled by `@ControllerAdvice` as it happened during execution inside the Spring application. You'll notice `org.springframework.messaging.core` in stack trace. The first error message occurred in Tomcat, and the request has never reached Spring application (`org.apache.coyote` in stack trace).